# Replace function does not meet expected results

Tags: java, replace

the following is my code:

```
char c;  
Random Generator = new Random();  
String text = FormulaArea.getText();  
String latestEqn = "";

for(c='a'; c<='z';c++)  
{  
  int randomNumber = Generator.nextInt(10000);  
  String convertToString = String.valueOf(randomNumber);  
  String sequence = String.valueOf(c);

  latestEqn = text.replaceAll(sequence,convertString);  
} 

TextField1.setText(latestEqn):
```

According to the above code, my expected result is:

```
Initial : a*b  
Result  : 100* 200
```

But the actual result gave me result as :

```
Initial : a*b  
Result  : a*b
```

I was doubt about what thing is going wrong, since compiler does not show any errors.

Answer (score 7):

This is because you discard `latestEqn` from previous loop iterations. Here is how you can fix it:

```
String latestEqn = text;
for(c='a'; c<='z';c++)
{  
  int randomNumber = Generator.nextInt(10000);  
  String convertToString = String.valueOf(randomNumber);  
  String sequence = String.valueOf(c);
  latestEqn = latestEqn.replaceAll(sequence,convertString);  
}
```

Since your code always starts from the original text, you would see an effect only if `text` contains letter `z`. For example, `x*z` would produce `x*1000` (or some other random number).

Answer (score 1):

You replace the variables in the `text` String and save the result in `latestEqn`, but the next iteration you replace the edited value again. Just get rid of the `latestEqn` variable:

```
String text = "a*b";

for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    int randomNumber = Generator.nextInt(10000);
    String convertToString = String.valueOf(randomNumber);
    String sequence = String.valueOf(c);
    text = text.replaceAll(sequence, convertToString);
}
```

Comment: If you do this then the original text is thrown away. I suspect the reason for adding the latestEqn variable was to be able to print both the original and the replaced versions later on. Thus I think @dasblinkenlight's answer is better

Comment: The original is still available with a `FormulaArea.getText()`, so nothing is thrown away.